# I can't use parallax gameref in vscode

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xZGl.png)
I just try to make game for my term project everything's just fine and then about the background parts I use parallax to make it can scroll but I can't use to make it works so that I can minimize it at any size when it tests, and the background does not mess up when resize.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Don't add code as an image (add it as a code block) and make sure that you formulate your question clearly with enough details so that we can help you properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `HasGameRef` mixin to your component to be able to use `gameRef`.